# Other Methods for Numerical Integration

Tags: integration, numerical-algorithms

I know four common methods for numerical integration of signals such as Midpoint, Trapezoid, Simpson's rule, and FFT integration property. Are there other methods?

Comment: Even basic Euler can have higher than `double` precision given enough sampling rate. What exactly are you interested in? For example, trapezoidal is used in SPICE engines and it's only limited to the `*tol` parameters -- which can be used with arbitrary precision, if you have enough coffee.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I am interested in converting accleration data in time domain to displacement.

Comment: Sounds to me you should be fine with the ones you've already mentioned but, you know better the precise context of what you need. I'll just say that, if this is part of a loop (e.g. dynamic) then even simple Euler will suffice (simple number crunching for the uC + the loop will compensate), and if it's offline, even a bilinear will do remarkably well for sampling 10x or better.

Comment: If you're integrating acceleration to get displacement, then a better integration method won't save you. The noise and measurement error of the acceleration is already enough to make the problem unfeasible and the uncertainty of the initial conditions is adding a lot on top. You can easily estimate the accumulated error with time and then understand that any reasonable medium to long term displacement predictions are impossible without support from other sensors.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac I have the real displacement but not acceleration. What you think?

Comment: @YazanAlatoom You just said in a previous comment, and also [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85298/how-to-double-integrate-signal-in-time-domain-using-fft-python) that you have acceleration and trying to get to displacement. Please make up your mind. It doesn't make sense to integrate displacement.

Comment: @YazanAlatoom that's really the point here: you want to calculate some theoretical function on all the  previous signal, call it "Integral". But how **well** that function gets *approximated* by your actual numerical method is a question that needs a precise definition of "well". You write "accuracy"; but accurate / true to what "true value"? **This depends on what you're trying to integrate, for what purpose**. So Jdip asking to clarify whether you're integrating acceleration to get displacement or integrating displacement (which I agree makes little sense) is necessary.

Comment: It would also be very important how your noise is distributed, what the correlation properties are.

Comment: @Jdip I am working on integrating displacement for some applications in my research field. I don't understand why it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am trying to integrate displacement from acceleration data. I have the displacement data collected from another device just to compare. My question is if there are other methods rather than those I mentioned above.

Comment: "I am trying to integrate displacement from acceleration data." so, you want to integrate acceleration data?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward Euler method:

$y(n) = y(n-1) + K*[t(n) - t(n-1)]*u(n-1)$

Backward Euler method:

$y(n) = y(n-1) + K*[t(n) - t(n-1)]*u(n)$

Trapezoidal method:

$y(n) = y(n-1) + K*[t(n)-t(n-1)]*[u(n)+u(n-1)]/2$

Source:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/discretetimeintegrator.html

Comment: Thanks a lot...